# How do I target a select list in a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a select list with a changing ID, within a div with a stable class.

When the selected option changes, I want to trigger some code.

How do I target the select list with the changing ID?

```
$(".stable".children(".select")).change(onSelectChange);
```

isn't doing it.  I'm really not sure how to target the little chameleon.

the HTML it looks like this:

```
<div class="stable">
    <label for="changing">Size:</label>
    <select name="changing" id="changing" class="Option required" onkeyup="this.blur();this.focus();onSelectChange();">...</select>
</div>
```

I hope it is obvious I don't mean the ID is specifically named "changing" - this ID changes with a previous product selection, and I'll need to target this no matter what ID has been assigned.  The class it has is constant, but has a space in it - part of a larger project, not my work.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your list already have an id : *supposed to be unique*

```
$('#changing').change(onSelectChange);
```

or the other way -

```
$('.stable select').change(onSelectChange);
```

Comment: OP explicitly states he can't use the ID : *"this ID changes with a previous product selection, and I'll need to target this no matter what ID has been assigned"*

Comment: Your first suggestion cannot apply in this case, but your second suggestion functions in the code.  Thank you to all who replied.  You have all helped me to learn more.

Answer (score 6):

Your selector is incorrect try this;

```
$(".stable").find("select").change(onSelectChange)..
```

And of course if you have only one of them then target it with id itself (But that doesn't seem to be the case with you asthe id changes)

```
 $('#changing').change(onSelectChange);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) :

```
$("select", ".stable").change(onSelectChange);
```